# Generate CSR that is connected with 2 domains

Tags: ssl, plesk

I'm using plesk, how do I get a CSR for 2 domains at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to generate a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) for your domains, then it depends on the type of SSL certificate that you will use. If each domain will have a separate SSL certificate, then you will need to generate one CSR for each domain.

If you are using the "Let's Encrypt" Plesk extension, then you should read the documentation on how to use it.

Comment: Im using godaddy's UCC SSL, SSL is working only for my "main domain" listed on the SSL. but not for the SANs. i called godaddy and they told me i should generate 1 CSR for both domain.

Comment: You should ask GoDaddy about how to generate 1 CSR for multiple domains